# No payment methods visible in cart

Tags: expresso-store

I have enabled Netaxept and Dummy in the settings, but {field:payment_method} still just outputs an empty select list in the cart. What could be wrong?

Edit. Here is my code.

```
{exp:store:checkout 
form_class="form default"
return="handlekurv/takk"
error_handling="inline"
error_delimiters='<span class="help-inline">|</span>'}

{if no_items}
    {redirect="butikk"}
{/if}

<section class="three-col">
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Faktureringsadresse</h2>
        <p>Navn: <strong>{billing_name}</strong></p>
        <p>Adresse: <strong>{billing_address1}</strong></p>
        <p>Sted: <strong>{billing_postcode}, {order_custom1}</strong></p>
        <p>Land: <strong>{billing_country_name}</strong></p>
        <p>Telefon: <strong>{billing_phone}</strong></p>
        <p>E-post: <strong>{order_email}</strong></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Leveringsadresse</h2>
        {if shipping_same_as_billing}
            <p>Samme som faktureringsadresse</p>
        {if:else}
            <p>Navn: <strong>{shipping_name}</strong></p>
            <p>Adresse: <strong>{shipping_address1}</strong></p>
            <p>Sted: <strong>{shipping_postcode}, {order_custom2}</strong></p>
            <p>Land: <strong>{shipping_country_name}</strong></p>
            <p>Telefon: <strong>{shipping_phone}</strong></p>
        {/if}
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <h2>Betalingsmåte</h2>
        {field:payment_method}
    </div>
</section> <!-- .three-col -->
<input type="submit" class="btn-flat green submit-cart" name="submit" value="Fullfør ordre" class="btn gray">
```

{/exp:store:checkout}

Comment: Can you post your template code?

Comment: Do you have any caching enabled on this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caching, but strangely, when I change dthe code to this, it suddenly started working.

```
<select id="payment_method" name="payment_method">
{payment_method_options}
</select>
```

Comment: It's possible some other EE plugin was causing issues with Store's `{field:payment_method}` tag